# Working with maps in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dictionary

I am creating an app for Windows Phone 8 that continuously tracks a users location. When the app finishes tracking the location, the activity of the user is displayed on the map using a polyline. I would now like to show some places of interest on the map as well as the polyline. I have tried the follwing code:

```
MapsTask mapsTask = new MapsTask();
mapsTask.SearchTerm = "hotel";
mapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;
mapsTask.Show();
```

However this displays a new map. I need the places of interest to be on the same map as the polyline. Can anyone give me any help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there're few things you can do with MapsTask.

MapControl may something you are looing for.
you can draw lines, make pushpins, add tap event on it. etc..

here are some reference may help you :

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-drawing-custom-pushpins-on-the-map-control-what-options-do-we-have

Comment: Thanks for this. Can I add a polyline with MapsTask?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206989(v=vs.105).aspx

it's seems no API about drawing in MapsTask...